# Mysql doesn't run

Tags: mysql, freebsd

I have no idea if this question fit to SO, but if it doesn't just close it...

The problem is that after migrating to another dedicated server, I can not get my MySQL server started, the loggs are saying the following:

```
120625 13:04:10 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/ropp.pid ended
120625 13:04:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/db/mysql
120625 13:04:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120625 13:04:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120625 13:04:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120625 13:04:29 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120625 13:04:29 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 104857600 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
120625 13:04:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
120625 13:04:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
120625 13:04:29 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
120625 13:04:29 [ERROR] Aborting

120625 13:04:29 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

120625 13:04:29 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/ropp.pid ended
```

Where is the problem and what do I have to do?
My MySQL server version is `5.5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that mysql configuration on your new server does not match the older one. The variable `innodb_log_file_size` is set to `5M` but actual size of log is 100MB. You need to change that value in `my.cnf`.

Shutdown MySQL server if it is running (it should not be). Edit `my.cnf` and change the value of `innodb_log_file_size` to `100M`

```
innodb_log_file_size = 100M
```

This should fix the problem. Start the server. If it doesn't work, then stop the server, move the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 to .bak and start the server again.